# Acknowledge receipt of producer message by client

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer

I have a Java class implementing a message producer, which sends messages to a queue named test. I have another class serving as a client, which gets messages from the same queue. I am confused on how to know if the message has been received at the client side. I read somewhere that I should use `message.acknowledge()`, but I do not know the proper way to do this. My code is shown below:

Producer:

```
public class Producer {
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    private static String subject = "que";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException,
            InterruptedException {

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

        // 
        int i = 0;
        //while(true)
        // {
        TextMessage message = session
                .createTextMessage("this is a gfjfjf " + i);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // 
        producer.send(message);
        i++;
        System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");
        System.out.println(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        MessageListener ML = session.getMessageListener();
        System.out.println(ML);
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
public class Consumer {

    private static String url = "failover://tcp://192.168.1.17:61616";

    private static String subject = "que";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

        // while(true)
        //  {
        Message message = consumer.receive();

        System.out.println(message);

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received message '" + textMessage.getText()
                    + "'");
        }
        if (session.getAcknowledgeMode() == Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE) {
            System.out.println(session.getAcknowledgeMode());
            System.out.println(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            message.acknowledge();
        }
        System.out.println(session.getAcknowledgeMode());
        System.out.println(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        message.acknowledge();

    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Perception do you have any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: its really rare to use client acknowledgment. Is there a particular reason you need it? If so, on your client side, create your session with `connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);`. Do note that in auto acknowledge mode that the runtime handles all this for you, including message redelivery.

Comment: @Perception ok but how will i check the acknoledgement

Comment: @Perception if it is acknoledged then will it send a true/false or anything

Comment: No, the acknowledge mode governs the interaction between the receiver (client) and the JMS provider (*not the message producer*). The producer is basically fire and forget in this scenario, leaving the provider and receiver to figure out if messages need to be redelivered etc etc. [Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html) is some reading you can do on the topic.

Comment: @Perception seem for example i have two systems connected via lan. Suppose there is a requirement that if PC1 gets the command ls then it will display the folders. So in this scenario i can use jms.
Now for example the client wants also the folder names so how will i do?
If you did not understand what i mean to say then please tell me

Comment: Seems like you want to implement some form of peer-to-peer communication.

Comment: @Perception can it be done using jms?

Comment: @Perception i am waiting for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use acknowledgements to check if the message has been received.

Actually messaging in general and JMS in particular is designed so that the sending application does not need to know if a message has reached the client. The concept is known as guaranteed delivery.

Acknowledments is a part of this. If you read a message of a queue and does not acknowlede it, the JMS broker will try to redeliver the message at a later time. You can take the concept to another level using transactions that you can commit or roll back as well.

If you really need a reciept to the original sender of the message, I suggest you send a message in reply. JMS has schemantics for Request/Reply using correlation ids and the ReplyTo field. You can google up a lot of examples, but [here is one at EIP](http://www.eaipatterns.com/RequestReplyJmsExample.html).

Comment: thanks ,i would be very much grateful to you if you edit my code and post it using the way you said

Comment: There is a come example in the link in my answer. You might want to look there. It's plain JMS the same way that you have implemented, so it should be trivial to implement.